How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sqrt x-1}{\ln \sqrt x}-1\right)\frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)\ln x}$
A friend handed me this integral a while ago
\begin{align}
I & =
\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{\sqrt{x} - 1}{\ln \left(\sqrt{x}\right)} - 1\right]\frac{{\rm d}x}{\left(x^{2} + x + 1\right)\ln\left(x\right)}
\\[2mm] & = -\,\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}} + \frac{7\psi_{1}\left(1/3\right)-\psi_{1}\left(1/6\right)}{4\pi\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$\psi_{1}\left(z\right)$ is the trigamma function.
The best method to my knowledge is to use Feynman's trick on the following function:
$$
J_{n} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{x^{n} - 1}{\ln\left(x\right)} - n\right]\frac{{\rm d}x}{\left(x^{2} + x + 1\right)\ln\left(x\right)}
$$
Differentiate with respect to $n$ twice and evaluate the following integral, then integrate twice, so on, so forth$\ldots$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{x^{2} + x + 1}{\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}+x^{-n}}{x^{2} + x + 1}{\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}(x^{n}+x^{-n})(1-x)\sum_{m=0}^\infty x^{3m}{\rm d}x
$$
This is equivalent to using
$$\frac{x^n-1}{\ln(x)}-n=\int_0^n (x^y-1)dy=\int_0^n \int_0^yx^z\ln(x)dzdy$$
I am asking if there is any other approach to evaluate $I$.

How exactly can we integrate $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{x^2+x+1}dx$ ?

The integrand behaves as $-1/\log x$ as  $x\to 0$ from above, Therefore, thie integral diverges at $0$.

@Souparna see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176217/compute-int-0-infty-fracx-alphax2x1dx?noredirect=1

@user64494 the limit of $1/\ln x$ as x approaches 0 converges, and so does the integrand at x approaches 0.

$$I=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sqrt x-1}{\ln \sqrt x}-1\right)\frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)\ln x}\overset{x=\frac1t}{=}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\frac1{\sqrt t}-1}{\ln \sqrt t}+1\right)\frac{dt}{(t^2+t+1)\ln t}$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,I=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt x-1}{\ln\sqrt x}\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)\frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)\ln x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{(\sqrt x-1)^2}{\sqrt x\ln^2x}\,\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}$$
$$\overset{x=e^t}{=}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cosh\frac t2-1}{\cosh t-\frac12}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac1{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cosh2\pi x-1}{\cosh 4\pi x-\frac12}\,\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
The integrand is regular at $x=0$, and we can consider
$$I(a)=\frac1{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cosh2\pi x-1}{\cosh 4\pi x-\frac12}\,\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1{4\pi a}\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cosh2\pi x-1}{\cosh 4\pi x-\frac12}\,\frac{dx}{a-ix}$$
$$=\frac1{4\pi a}\Re\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cosh2\pi x-1}{\cosh 4\pi x-\frac12}\ln(a-ix)dx=\frac1{4\pi a}\Re\frac{\partial}{\partial a}J(a)$$
To evaluate $J(a)$ we integrate in the complex plane along a rectangular contour $C:\, -R\to R\to R+i\to-R+i\to-R$
Noting that $\cosh(2\pi(x+i))=\cos(2\pi x)$ and $\ln(a-ix)=\ln\Gamma\big(a-i(x+i)\big)-\ln\Gamma(a-ix)$, and that integral along the lines $R\to R+i$ and $-R+i\to-R$ tend to zero as $R\to\infty$
$$J(a)=-\oint_C\frac{\cosh 2\pi z-1}{\cosh4\pi z+\frac12}\ln\Gamma(a-iz)dz=-2\pi i\underset{z=\frac i6,\frac{5i}6,\frac i3,\frac{2i}3}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{(\cosh 2\pi z-1)\ln\Gamma(a-iz)}{\cosh4\pi z+\frac12}$$
$$=\frac1{2\sqrt3}\Big(3\ln\Gamma(a+2/3)-3\ln\Gamma(a+1/3)+\ln\Gamma(a+1/6)-\ln\Gamma(a+5/6)\Big)$$
$$I(a)=\frac1{8\pi a\sqrt3}\Big(3\psi(a+2/3)-3\psi(a+1/3)+\psi(a+1/6)-\psi(a+5/6)\Big)$$
Using the property $\psi(1-x)-\psi(x)=\pi\cot\pi x$, it is straightforward to check that
$$3\psi(2/3)-3\psi(1/3)+\psi(1/6)-\psi(5/6)=0$$
Hence, decomposing $I(a)$ near $a=0$
$$I(0)=\frac1{8\pi\sqrt3}\left(3\psi_1\Big(\frac23\Big)-3\psi_1\Big(\frac13\Big)+\psi_1\Big(\frac16\Big)-\psi_1\Big(\frac56\Big)\right)$$
Using the property $\displaystyle \psi_1(1-x)+\psi_1(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2\pi x}$
$$\boxed{\,\,I=\frac1{4\pi\sqrt3}\left(\psi_1\Big(\frac16\Big)-3\psi_1\Big(\frac13\Big)\right)=0.32306594...\,\,}$$
Differentiating the duplication formula for gamma-function
$$4\psi_1(2z)=\psi_1(z)+\psi_1\big(z+1/2\big)$$
taking $z=\frac13$ and using again the property of digamma-function, we can get the answer in the original form, or the expression that uses only $\psi_1\Big(\frac13\Big)$. Numeric check confirms the results.

How did you produce the initial substitution of $x=\frac1t$?

@Grey $$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sqrt x-1}{\ln \sqrt x}-1\right)\frac{dx}{(x^2+x+1)\ln x}\overset{x=\frac1t}{=}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\frac1{\sqrt t}-1}{-\ln \sqrt t}-1\right)\frac{dt}{(\frac1{t^2}+\frac1t+1)(-\ln t)t^2}$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\frac{1-\sqrt t}{\sqrt t}}{\ln \sqrt t}+1\right)\frac{dt}{(t^2+t+1)\ln t}$$
There was a typo in this line of the post, but I corrected it 3 hours ago. Taking half sum of the integral and the integral after transformation, we see that the second term ($\frac1{(t^2+t+1)\ln t}$) cancels.
